# Delete Join Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I am trying to use Delete statement in my Stored Procedure but it is giving me an error saying,

Invalid object name 'BRWSQLDC'.

and below is my Delete Statement:

```
set @Query = 'DELETE FROM ' + @DestLinkServer + ' FROM .HL2_61.dbo.ArtPDF AP JOIN .HL2_61.dbo.Article A on A.ArticleID = AP.ArticleID ' + ' WHERE ArticleKey = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Id)
```

When I execute it as below

```
DELETE FROM BRWSQLDC FROM .HL2_61.dbo.ArticlePDF AP JOIN .HL2_61.dbo.Article A on A.ArticleID = AP.ArticleID  WHERE ArticleKey = -1591276581
```

> Error is: Invalid object name 'BRWSQLDC'.

And if I try to execute the code as below:

```
'DELETE FROM ' + @DestLinkServer + ' .HL2_61.dbo.ArticlePDF AP JOIN .HL2_61.dbo.Article A on A.ArticleID = AP.ArticleID ' + ' WHERE ArticleKey = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Id)
```

when passing the values,

```
DELETE FROM BRWSQLDC .HL2_61.dbo.ArticlePDF AP JOIN .HL2_61.dbo.Article A on A.ArticleID = AP.ArticleID  WHERE ArticleKey = -1591276581
```

error I am getting is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'AP'.

Please help me how to join 2 tables in a delete and then delete that in the server if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move you alias to after your delete, but you should also identify the table the `ArticleKey` comes from

```
DELETE AP
FROM BRWSQLDC.HL2_61.dbo.ArticlePDF AP 
JOIN BRWSQLDC.HL2_61.dbo.Article A   -- preface this with your server name for clarity
    ON A.ArticleID = AP.ArticleID  
WHERE A.ArticleKey = -1591276581
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a join but a proper WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

When you use join you have to tell from which table you want to delete rows:

```
DELETE dbo.Customer
FROM dbo.Customer cust INNER JOIN dbo.Person pers ON pers.ID_CUST = cust.ID_CUST
```